# Blogger Plugin - Cross Domain Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain, blogger

I am trying to make a blogger plugin where I am sending some information from the blog page and doing some analytics and sending the result on the visitor's page. I was sending the page content using ajax call. It gives the error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.penpatron.com/getContentAffiliateAdvertising.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.cseblog.com' is therefore not allowed access."

I understand the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. I am wondering how do other companies make blogger plugins.

I am using a blogger plugin and I have included the following code and its working fine.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.skimresources.com/js/56583X1334255.skimlinks.js"></script>`. What is skimresources doing different?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend suggested JSONP. That should do it.